# Delete oldest Files in directory

Tags: c#

I have a question about deleting oldest file in a directory.

Situation is as follows:

I would like to limit the amount of files in a directory to 5 files. Once that limit is reached I would like it to find the oldest file in the directory and delete it, so that the new file can be copied in.

I have been told to use filewatcher, however I have never used that function before.

Comment: I guess you just need to check it when you have new file to save there so you don't need to use filewatcher.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
using System.IO; using System.Linq;

foreach (var fi in new DirectoryInfo(@"x:\whatever").GetFiles().OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTime).Skip(5))
    fi.Delete();
```

Change the directory name, the argument in Skip(), and LastWriteTime to however you define 'oldest'.

The above gets all the files, orders them youngest first, skips the first 5, and deletes the rest.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` to get the files in the folder, order them by `CreationTime` with `Enumerable.OrderByDescending`, use `Enumerable.Take(5)` to get the 5 last created files. If there are more the `List.ForEach` will delete them.

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo("path").EnumerateFiles()
     .OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime)
     .Skip(5)
     .ToList();
files.ForEach(f => f.Delete());
```